# json.dumps ValueError: Extra data unable to dump json outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-watson

I am trying to use speech to text watson api, but when I set the `interim_results = True` I got the value error. Please help me:)

```
with open(join(dirname(__file__), './audio-file.wav'), 'rb') as audio_file:
 print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(
     audio_file, content_type='audio/wav', timestamps=True, interim_results =True, word_confidence=True), indent=2))
```

The error output:

> [image: The error output]

However when I set the `interim_results = False` I got the output which was properly working.

The output when the `interim_results = False`:

> [image: The output when the interim_results=False]

I think that the reason will be related with multiple json outputs but I don't know how to solve it because this is json.dumps:) So I can not refer json.loads value error cases to solve this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With interim_results=true, the service sends back multiple JSON blobs, with the expectation that you will parse them individually as they arrive. This is useful if you want to, for example, display near-realtime transcriptions.

If you're just doing a one-off transcription and don't need to display the text in near-real-time, I would recommend leaving interim_results set to false.

You *could* split the result around `}\s*{` (where one JSON blob ends and the next one begins), and then parse each individual chunk as JSON (restoring the `}` and `{`s if necessary), but it wouldn't really gain you anything since the complete final results would already be there.

Alternatively, if you do need/want near-realtime updates, the WebSocket interface makes this a little easier because each JSON chunk arrives in it's own message - check out https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python for an example.

Comment: Thanks but are there any methods to split the json result during the process? I hope that someone could give the code for that.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but it shouldn't be too hard if you wanted to create it. You could even send a Pull Request to have it included with the SDK: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk